# Keeping HTML format in <pre> (in WordPress)

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm experiencing odd behavior.

I am using some HTML tags inside `<pre>`. For example:

```
<pre>
<b>abc</b>
</pre>
```

In order to first render them I am using the following PHP code in functions.php:

```
add_filter('the_content','html_entity_decode');
```

Which gives:

```
abc
```

This solves the problem, and the HTML is first rendered and the output is displayed in `<pre>`.

However, if I wish to use the plugin "[SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/)" with some brush, it automatically renders the HTML inside the  back to HTML.

I am not even sure what to ask in order to figure out what is causing this. Any suggestion would be welcomed.

Comment: id say use another plugin, or you could try to modify the code for SyntaxHighlighter Evolved to make it so that it doesnt add html tags.

Comment: Try playing around with the third argument to `add_filter`. The third argument is `priority` and determines when the filter is applied in relation to other filters. By default it is 10. Try a high number like 99.

Comment: Hi @KodosJohnson - I tried it and it doesn't work...